# Css layout overlapping

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hello i am trying to get my columns in css to go down the page. Im new to css but know some css for messing around with things.

My columns are sat next to each other like so

collum1  collum2

I am trying to make them go down the page like so

collum1
collum2

But seems not wanting to move...

Here is my page source for the left side bar.

```
<div class="col1">

            <div class="box" id="news">

                <h1 id="news_handle">Home</h1>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../register.php">Register</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="bar">
                    <span>
                <span></span></span></div>

            </div>


  <div class="box" id="events"></div>
</div>


<div class="co22">

            <div class="box" id="news">

                <h1 id="news_handle">22</h1>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.php">1212</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../register.php">1212</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="bar">
                    <span>
                <span></span></span></div>

            </div>


  <div class="box" id="events"></div>
</div>
```

Then here is my css style / file

```
body
{
    background: #122530 url('./images/background.jpg') repeat-y;
    text-align: center;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial, Hevetica, Sans-serif;
}

a,a:visited
{
    color: #1e3f51;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a img,a:visited img
{
    border: 0;
}


/**
 * General Structure
 */

div#container
{
    width: 873px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}


/**
 * Banner/Nav
 */
div#banner
{
    height: 255px;
    background: url('./images/banner.jpg') no-repeat;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    clear: both;
}

div#nav
{
    background: url('./images/nav_bg.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px 2px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

    div#nav a
    {
        color: #ffffff;
        font: bold 10px Tahoma, Arial, Hevetica, Sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 12px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 11px 7px 11px 7px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 1px 0 0 0;
    }

    div#nav a:hover
    {
        background: url('./images/nav_hover.jpg') repeat-x;
    }


/**
 * Columns
 */
div.col1,div.col2
{
    float: left;
}

div.col1
{
    width: 190px;
}

div.col2
{
    width: 479px;
    margin: 0 7px 0 7px;
}


/**
 * Columns
 */
div.co22
{
    float: left;
}

div.co22
{
    width: 190px;
}

div.co22
{
    width: 479px;
    margin:25px 50px 75px;
}


/**
 * Box Elements
 */
div.box
{
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

div.box h1
{
    height: 29px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: 15px 'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #112735;
    cursor: move;
}

    div.col2 div.box h1
    {
        cursor: auto;
    }

    div.col1 div.box h1
    {
        background: url('./images/col1_head.jpg') no-repeat;
    }

    div.col2 div.box h1
    {
        background: url('./images/col2_head.jpg') no-repeat;
    }


div.box div.bar
{
    height: 23px;
    clear: both;
    background: url('./images/box_foot.jpg') repeat-x;
    color: #d1e3ee;
    font: 11px Tahoma;
}

    div.box div.bar span
    {
        height: 23px;
        display: block;
        background: url('./images/box_foot_left.jpg') no-repeat;
        float: left;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    div.box div.bar span span
    {
        height: 23px;
        width: 2px;
        background: url('./images/box_foot_right.jpg') top right no-repeat;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        margin: -4px;
    }

    div.box div.bar a
    {
        display: block;
        color: #d1e3ee;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    div.box div.bar a.right
    {
        text-align: right;
    }

div.content
{
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
    background: #c1dae8 url('./images/body_bg.jpg') repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

    div.content p
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px;
    }


/**
 * Lists
 */
ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

    ul li
    {
        background: url('./images/list_item.jpg') repeat-x;
        border: 1px solid #112735;
        border-top: 0px;
        height: 14px;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    ul li a
    {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 14px;
    }

ul.sponsors li
{
    background: url('./images/list_sponsor.jpg') repeat-x;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
}

    ul.sponsors li a
    {
        height: 48px;
    }


/**
 * Footer
 */
div#footer
{
    background: url('./images/footer.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 36px;
    clear: both;
}

div#footer a
{
    display: block;
    height: 36px;
}

div#footer a span
{
    display: none;
}
```

I have been awake 12 hours looking though google and trying to make them down under each other with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Have looked at your code using firebug.

Why are you inserting more than one

```
<div class="col1">
    ...
</div>
```

You should just place all boxes in the same col1. You do not need two of these.

Basically, do not use two versions of col1 but place all boxes in the same col1, one below each other.

```
<div class="col1">
    <div class="box" id="news" style="position: relative; "></div>
    <div class="box" id="events" style="position: relative; "/> </div>
    <div class="box" id="news" style="position: relative; "></div>
    <div class="box" id="events" style="position: relative; "/> </div>
</div>
```

If you need to access each box directly then separate them by using different ids, id="news1", id="news2" ...

---EDIT---

Well I have tried it and look:

[image]

[image]

HTML for one of your col1 (same for both sides).

```
<div class="col1">

    <div class="box" id="news">

        <h1 id="news_handle">Home</h1>

    <ul>

    </ul>

    <div class="bar">
        <span>
        <span></span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:20px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="box" id="sponsors">

    <h1 id="news_handle">Home</h1>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="../register.php">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bar"> <span> <span></span></span></div>
    </div>


    <div class="box" id="affiliates"></div>


    <div class="box" id="items"></div>


</div>
```

I have not changed your CSS, that is what is live

Comment: and if not this, set col1 and col2 to float:left; and increase the width of col2 so that the other col1 cannot go on the right hand side of it. However, this may push the wrong div out of place. Try it out...

Comment: i don't think you understand still i need two of the news_handle    See the whole home box ? Witht he links in ? I need another one just under it. I don't mean put more links in under the login and register i need another whole box which the login and register links are in just under it.....

Comment: I do understand. What I have suggested will do this. Your styling knows that they are separate boxes due their individual styling. Have you even tried out my answer yet? If you need a space between boxes just use <div style="height:20px;">&nbsp;</div> Or wrap all your col1 divs in a parent div.

Comment: yep have tryied that but just shows up letters like so fgfg no box no nothing

Comment: http://pokemontoxic.com/nicky/ take a look ... The side bar has gone... the left side with your code

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest removing the

```
float:left;
```

from columns... and add:

```
display:block;
```

Comment: That has put it under neath but now the other divs have messed up. http://oi41.tinypic.com/14e429x.jpg there is a screen shot the big box is a center box then the two boxes on the top ment to be the left side bar. has you cans ee its on top of the center section and not on the left side...

Comment: this is because your sidebar and centerbox should float left and col1 and col2 should not. Refer to Dusean's answer.

Comment: can you send a screenshot of how you would like it to be?

Comment: http://pokemontoxic.com/nicky/ take a look the left side bar is ok there but when i try and put another box there e.g the box which says login and register and the total users it will fly across the page. All i want is to add another box under the home box. So add another home box under the home box..... If you get me ???

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put both columns into a div:

```
<div class="sidebar"> 
       <div id="col1"></div> 
       <div id="col2"></div>
</div>
```

Now `float: left;` for both center box and left sidebar. In order to have col1 and col2 underneath each other use as Philip said `display: block;`

Edit:

As you already have the first column on the left side if you want the second column on the right side of the box to the left side under the first column then just add the it like following:

```
<div id="col1">
   First column content

   <div id="col1>
       Second column content
   </div>
</div> 
<div id="col2"></div>
```

[Link to the html file with css](http://jsfiddle.net/d47Vs/2/)

Comment: This is a forum for assisstance and you have had many solutions to your issue. I have tested mine, you have a screenshot of somebody elses. Are you unable to come to a compromise between them. Once again you do not need two versions of col1, the boxes are separate from col1.

Comment: What about the right hand bar tho ? I need a right hand bar and a left hand side bar.  But of course 2 on the left and 1 onthe right

Comment: Don´t change anything in col1 after col2 on right side and it will stay there....

Comment: could you share the css file and the side bars ? Because it don't look like that on mine with your code http://pokemontoxic.com/nicky/

Comment: There is no change in CSS file, I just change the structure of HTML div tags.

Comment: Im using the style up top were i posted and im not getting what your getting in screen shot. You can check http://pokemontoxic.com/nicky/login.php there is no box .........

Answer (score 0):

Here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/d47Vs/

Comment: Ill test this now ( uploading it now ) and will get back to you by posting here

Comment: This still does not work test url is http://pokemontoxic.com/nicky/index.php  has you can see a total mess :)

Comment: I think like Philip Bevan said, it might pay to show us how you want the end result to look so we can help better

Comment: pokemontoxic.com/nicky take a look the left side bar is ok there but when i try and put another box there e.g the box which says login and register and the total users it will fly across the page. All i want is to add another box under the home box. So add another home box under the home box..... If you get me ??? ??

Comment: I might be missing the point but i'm unsure why you've got draggable items? It sounds like your just trying to add another block in there below the login box, therefore you need to add the new block in your html. Currently i can see you have an 'events' div there but it's not showing because there's no content inside of it